# Why does the asterisk go up when you switch from input to another mode?

Tags: homework, input

So my teacher said that if we solved this question we would get extra credit (please tell me if I'm being too vague and I will clarify)
When you change from the input to the regular text mode in Mathematica, the asterisk (*) goes up, and sometimes it doesn't. Why does the asterisk go up? Thank you so much!

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a response to your first question, until you edited it to be something completely different.  Never do that again.  Post a new question instead.

Comment: The second iteration of this question belongs in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @QuantumDot I am so sorry-first time using this site, and I thought I was writing a new question not deleting my old one...can you still please answer my first question? Why does the asterisk go up when you switch from input to another mode? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've rolled the question back to the original one.

Comment: It is not appropriate to ask for the answer to a homework assignment, especially since it is worth extra credit. @QuantumDot, it's your choice of course to answer this if you wish, but I would suggest that we don't want to encourage young learners (and users of this site) to get answers to their homework questions here.

Comment: @march I'm not cheating-I'm allowed to use the internet and Mathematica resources, but I'm not allowed to ask other students. This is a "fun/trivia" extra credit assignment.

Comment: @desperatestudent. Then I rescind the "especially since it is worth extra credit" and "young learners" parts, but it is still true that this site is not for getting answers to homework questions. See if you can do some exploration about the situation yourself, then include what you tried and were able to come up with in your post, and then perhaps we can help.

Comment: @march Ok, I came up with this theory then and was wondering if you could tell me whether it's correct...In Mathematica, the asterisk (*) goes up when you switch from input because in input the asterisk signifies the Times function. When you switch it to another mode it no longer means Times and therefore the asterisk is elevated to show that it no longer means to multiply.

Comment: You might learn more if you figured it out.... :)

Answer (score 5):

The theory you propose in your comment to the question puts you on the right path. But there is a little more to it than that.

In an input mode (and there is more than one) when you type in an asterisk it is interpreted as `Times` and is rendered by a special glyph, unicode 22C6 (unicode name: STAR OPERATOR)

In a text mode (again, there are more than one). it is not interpreted and is rendered by unicode 002A (unicode name: ASTERISK), which in most fonts is rendered as a raised asterisk because its traditional use is to indicate a footnote.

It is quite easy to get both kinds of stars in a text mode cell by inserting ASTERISK from the keyboard and STAR OPERATOR from the Special Characters palette.

[image: text]

The above cell, when opened by <kbd>Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (OS X) or<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>  (Other systems) looks like

[image: cell]

which clearly shows the difference between the two characters. And, yes, you can type in "\[Star]" from the keyboard to get STAR OPERATOR.